# How to identify potential incompatibilies when increasing Android target SDK

Tags: android, android-api-levels

I want to attempt to add a feature (notification channels) which requires target SDK level 26 to an open-source Android project that currently targets SDK level 22.

Looking at the documentation for notification channels, I saw something disturbing: apparently increasing the target level can cause previously valid uses of the API to function differently — in this case, notifications that don’t specify a channel will no longer be displayed. That tells me there could be other things that would break as well just from changing the target level.

How can I find every API call in the project that I need to examine for possible incompatibility when changing from level 22 to level 26? Alternatively, is there a way to isolate sections of code so that the code I’m not changing still uses level 22, and only the new code uses 26?

Comment: You don't need to change your `targetSdkVersion` to use new APIs - that's controlled by the `compileSdkVersion` as per [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd)

Comment: @ianhanniballake: I read the post you linked. Is this saying, then, that if I have source that works on level 22, and I leave target level 22 (which is set in the project files) but compile at level 27 (which I see Android Studio has chosen for me), everything that worked in level 22 will still work, _and_ I’ll be able to use anything defined in level 27... even where behaviors differ?

Comment: @ianhanniballake: For example, despite this:

[“Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel or it will not appear.”](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels)

I’ll be able to use notification channels in new code I add, but old code creating notifications from before setting a channel was required will still work, too? Wonderful if it’s true, but it sounds like the compiler would have to read my mind to do that.

Comment: That's correct (and exactly why they are two separate values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to attempt to add a feature (notification channels) which requires target SDK level 26

If you have `targetSdkVersion` set to 26 or higher, then notification channels are required. If your `targetSdkVersion` is set below 26, notification channels are not required, but AFAIK you can still set them up, if you are running on an API Level 26+ device. Personally, I have never tried this; keeping your `targetSdkVersion` up to date is fairly important in modern Android app development.

> How can I find every API call in the project that I need to examine for possible incompatibility when changing from level 22 to level 26?

In general, you can't. You are welcome to read the release notes for Android; in the past couple of releases, Google has been better about specifically calling out the changes that are triggered by `targetSdkVersion`. You can also read the JavaDocs for the associated `Build.VERSION_CODES` value (e.g., [the JavaDoc for `M`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#M)), as they list changes triggered by `targetSdkVersion`. The IDE might give you some warnings. Beyond that, it's a matter of testing.

> Alternatively, is there a way to isolate sections of code so that the code I’m not changing still uses level 22, and only the new code uses 26?

Put them in completely independent apps. Otherwise, no. The `targetSdkVersion` is a per-app setting, not a per-file or per-class setting.

Comment: Thanks. I think I get the picture now. This means that for an open-source project of significant size, just getting to where the Target SDK can be increased to a new level is itself a daunting change request. It looks like this project has been struggling with it.

Well, getting to commit-worthy changes would be way down the road for me, anyway; though if I’m just doing it for myself, it might be easier to forget about notification channels and do what I want in a more ham-fisted but less complicated way.

Comment: @Coises: "This means that for an open-source project of significant size, just getting to where the Target SDK can be increased to a new level is itself a daunting change request" -- possibly. It's not like *tons* of things change behavior based on `targetSdkVersion`. Having a low `targetSdkVersion` is just another form of technical debt, like using an out-of-date edition of a library.